# Prepopulating Access Form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form that we use for data entry, to make it easier I would like to have some of the fields prepopulate based on the EmployeeID field, for example once I put in my employee id then the EmployeeName field would be Auto populate with John Doe, and Gender would be Male and EEOC would be White, etc. Is this at all possible to do? It would be based of the data in another table title EmpData.

Comment: What you are trying to do is certainly by possible in Access with VBA and events, such as the form load event http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821347(v=office.15).aspx.  The specific steps I will not provide as I have not used Access in years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the AfterUpdate event of EmployeeID, you could put something like (untested code, so it needs to be tweaked a bit):

```
Dim db as DAO.Database
Dim rec as DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDB
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from EmpData where EmployeeID = " & Me.EmployeeID & "")

Me.EmployeeName = rec("EmployeeName")
Me.Gender = rec("Gender")
Me.EEOC = rec("EEOC")
etc...

Set rec = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

If EmployeeID is a Text field, it will need to be surrounded by single quotes in the "Set rec" line.  Like this:

```
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from EmpData where EmployeeID = '" & Me.EmployeeID & "'")
```

Comment: I apologize for my lack of knowledge but could you please clarify what you mean by the after update event

Comment: Look at the Properties of your text box.  One of them is AfterUpdate.

Comment: Yes.  The proper event for this to happen is the AfterUpdate event.  This way, it will fire after you have entered the EmployeeID as you requested in your question.

Comment: Should the rec("EEOC") [using that as an example] be the names of the fields in the table where the data to populate the boxes is coming from?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  You can also reference them by their column order (i.e. rec(0), rec(1), etc...) but it's generally a better idea to reference them by their name.

Comment: I get the error: RUN TIME ERROR 13: TYPE MISMATCH and it highlights the whole SET REC line

Comment: Do you know if the Data Type of EmployeeID is Numeric or Text?  As I said in my answer, if it's Text then you have to use the last line I posted.  Type Mismatch indicates that you're trying to perform a Numeric operation on a Text field, or a Text operation on a Numeric field.

Comment: I used the second line, it is a text

Comment: the code looks like 
    Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from EmpData where EmployeeID = '" & Me.txtEmpID & "'")

Comment: This stuff is really hard to explain to a new user, and I don't mean that in disrespect.  It's just intuitive for me and I'm not a teacher.  That being said, if you hover your mouse over Me.txtEmpID when the code stops there, it should tell you what it thinks Me.txtEmpID is equal to.  If you know how to do this, recreate that whole SELECT statement into a blank query and see if if returns anything, or if it autocorrects itself.  Usually you can see what Access doesn't like by doing that.  And by "recreate" I mean, plug in an actual value instead of using the "Me.txtEmpID" variable.

Comment: Yes it works just fine when I run it in a separate query. I run it with my ID and it works, then I run it with the Me.TxtEmpID in there and it comes up with blank fields but all the column headings are there

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49488/discussion-between-user2119980-and-johnny-bones)

Answer (score 1):

If you create a query that joins the two tables, then Access will do it all for you automatically. Then you should use that query as the DataSource for the form.

```
SELECT MyDataTable.*, EmpData.*
FROM MyDataTable LEFT JOIN EmpData
ON MyDataTable.EmployeeID = EmpData.EmployeeID;
```

Doing this, you might want to lock the columns coming from EmpData from being possible to edit.

In your form, you show the fields from the MyDataTable and the relevant fields from EmpData. Any fields in MyDataTable that should be filled in from EmpData should not be shown to the user. 
I.e. you show the EmployeeName from EmpData and not from MyTableData.

In the AfterUpdate event on EmployeeID you copy the data from EmpData to MyTableData

```
Me.RecordSet!MyTableData.EmployeeName = Me.RecordSet!EmpData.EmployeeName
```

Comment: Can you explain how this query is going to update a form as the OP requested?

Comment: It is all matter of definition. The query WILL populate the fields in the form, if the fields in the form is showing the employer name etc from the EmpData fields of the query. If the form is showing the employee name from the other data-table in the wuery it WONT be populated.

Comment: @JohnnyBones - in other words--if the form is bound to the source table/query, then by definition it will auto-populate with values from that source table/query.

Comment: @JohnnyBones - Yes. It is not the form that does the magic, i think it is some more fundamental functionality, because it works the same when you open the query and add a row there.